# Disable IIS7 URL Rewrite inheritance on a per site basis?

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

I have many global IIS7 URL Rewrite rules and they by default apply to all sites. Well there are several sites that i would like to disable this rewrite inheritance on for all rules. How can I do this? I tried the following without joy:

```
 <rewrite>
<rules>
    <clear />
</rules>
  </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, that cannot be done:

> **Global rewrite rules** are used to define server-wide URL rewriting
>   logic. These rules are defined within *applicationHost.config* file
>   and they **cannot be overridden or disabled on any lower configuration
>   levels, such as site or virtual directory**. Global rules always
>   operate on the absolute URL path (that is, requested URI without the
>   server name).

and

> Global rule set is always evaluated first, and after that distributed
>   rule set will be evaluated by using a URL string produced by global
>   rule set.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/468/using-global-and-distributed-rewrite-rules/

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to move the functionality you need out of the global rules and into the web.config for your sites, you can add a condition on each rule to either opt-in or opt-out of each rule based on the presence of a local file for that site. This would allow you to deploy a common set of code and config, but with local/per-site customization.

Example of an opt-in rule:

```
        <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                <!-- Opt-in to rule via presense of a local file -->
                <add input="{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/Local/rewrite-rule-enable-https.txt" matchType="IsFile" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
```

Note: The Local folder is not deployed, but rather used to store per-site files.

So essentially this rule does not turn on unless a file called "rewrite-rule-enable-https.txt" is found in the /Local folder on site.